# PHP : Get private key from a single line private key

Tags: php, openssl, rsa

I am trying to create a `JWT` token. The other server is storing the public key in a single line and using that for validation.

Also, the public key being used for validation is in single line.

So, to generate the correct JWT token, what I think is I should also use the private key in a single line (may be with `\n` or may be without).

I am using [openssl_sign](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) to generate the token, which uses `openssl_reource` as key. I get that paramter from [openssl_pkey_get_private](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php).

But problem which happens in this case is, it either accepts the `pem` file path, or  the key in `PEM` string format. So, if I pass the `private_key` as a single line, it doesn't give me the required output.

So, how can I resolve this. As I see other language libraries able to generate signature by passing private key in a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP the key can be formatted with line breaks or as a one-liner (with `\n`). Both works. In the following example I use a 512-bit encrypted RSA-key for simplicity (although in practice a larger key (>= 2048 bit) must be used for security reasons):

```
<?php

// Private key: 512 bit for simplicity
// Passphrase: MyPassphrase
// openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.pem 512
$privKeyEnc = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,8F2D6F9594B3D379BF9D9748BD174458

RP2fyz1VNBKHiCadC5B9fjxV7z7AMAqbsN2vykFfPhdUFsxlJaecEeTMT7s6IbZN
Pr80+ljLjJ0SxJiK+j8DAc/Wrf+qyYUFcWbsvOhUIPyB5ww9+mEeIERJCigsyZJ7
k/Apau/BypdC9vCXKB3wM9FcmvP1g/ZwVoXfN3TIPEfWTktvuf74yFNoIaVbZAK/
+tzAGduu9wLkr6WTq4Isqy/IPjVCp9VwH1wNnz+hjkO7oELcCpFieIvAidUMKBR9
EdexLQCimbOl2wlfRNLincK8+FDOVWx6ElFFQlhzyWQCt8ed1fdiAggKxOco4Ww2
tFjIzaO4KXlbc9JFGd9PzigpftN/aHbk3c+x0E+3q5u8eySai4vgk38s1KaE7rn/
rarCgtGxOlbbTkI3opkjIrGlrsEyexKtS23mI/Dgcco=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

// One-liner using \n
$privKeyEnc_1Line = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nProc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\nDEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,8F2D6F9594B3D379BF9D9748BD174458\n\nRP2fyz1VNBKHiCadC5B9fjxV7z7AMAqbsN2vykFfPhdUFsxlJaecEeTMT7s6IbZN\nPr80+ljLjJ0SxJiK+j8DAc/Wrf+qyYUFcWbsvOhUIPyB5ww9+mEeIERJCigsyZJ7\nk/Apau/BypdC9vCXKB3wM9FcmvP1g/ZwVoXfN3TIPEfWTktvuf74yFNoIaVbZAK/\n+tzAGduu9wLkr6WTq4Isqy/IPjVCp9VwH1wNnz+hjkO7oELcCpFieIvAidUMKBR9\nEdexLQCimbOl2wlfRNLincK8+FDOVWx6ElFFQlhzyWQCt8ed1fdiAggKxOco4Ww2\ntFjIzaO4KXlbc9JFGd9PzigpftN/aHbk3c+x0E+3q5u8eySai4vgk38s1KaE7rn/\nrarCgtGxOlbbTkI3opkjIrGlrsEyexKtS23mI/Dgcco=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

// Public key: 
// Passphrase: MyPassphrase
// openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
$pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAMjYQLbdIVgKX1mSyKijOIpmlB9YWui1
KoCniRNHUPEsxth+o9fZXZMo1gzh9ZlFs6VLiyU7kv2+5QElOnhNzwcCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

// One-liner using \n
$pubKey_1Line = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAMjYQLbdIVgKX1mSyKijOIpmlB9YWui1\nKoCniRNHUPEsxth+o9fZXZMo1gzh9ZlFs6VLiyU7kv2+5QElOnhNzwcCAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$dataToSign = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

// Signing
//$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private("$privKeyEnc", "MyPassphrase");     // also works
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private("$privKeyEnc_1Line", "MyPassphrase"); 
openssl_sign($dataToSign, $signature, $privateKey, 'sha256'); 
$signatureBase64 = base64_encode($signature);
print("Signature (Base64): ".$signatureBase64."<br>");

// Verifying
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public("$pubKey");                             
//$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public("$pubKey_1Line");                     // also works
$verified = openssl_verify($dataToSign, $signature, $publicKey,'sha256');
print("Verification: ".$verified."<br>");

/*
Output:
Signature (Base64): KVuUd+xy6at0emmhF20rbiD9lWzIN9euwKbeEm7aMvxqEkJ68HrjAoDJ37R3QGPI24woXY3TON9pahAhx+YNhQ==
Verification: 1
*/

?>
```

Comment: Can we generate by removing the header and tail also? As my current requirement is that only, but openssl needs header and tail.

Comment: [`openssl_pkey_get_private`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php) expects a key in PEM format. The [PEM format](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem) has a header and footer, so OpenSSL requires both. But even if you only have the body of the PEM key, you can easily add header and footer. Or are your keys in a different format? Maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will reiterate my problem.

The external server where my jwt token is getting validated they do that considering a token which should be generated without headers and footers.
But as you said our function works only in that format.

So, in the php domain, is there ANY way to do that?

Comment: The header and footer of the key do not contain _any_ information that affects the encryption, i.e. they only identify the key format. You may be using keys in [DER format](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem) that do not have a header and footer. If this is the case, the keys must first be converted to PEM format so that they can be used for the openssl functions. Maybe the validation problem is not caused by the keys at all.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense actually. The header and footer are just for parsing. I generated the key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f private.key`
But there must be some other reason which is causing the validation issue and not this as you said.

Comment: Here you can find a PHP code that creates a JWT token using a test key. The code is transparent, maybe you can use it to narrow down the problem: https://pastebin.com/sKrvkAYn. The code can be executed e.g. in http://phpfiddle.org/.